# Освобождение памяти в Java после обнуления ссылки

Tags: java

Объявляю в классе массив

```
int[] arr;
```

В обработчике нажатия кнопки инициализирую его ста миллионами:

```
arr = new int[100000000];
```

Смотрю в диспетчере задач, памяти заняло 400Мб

В обработчике другой кнопки обнуляю массив и даже вызываю сборщик мусора

```
arr=null;
System.gs();
```

Но памяти сколько было занято, столько и остается, хотя объект явно обнулен. 
Бывает вообще такое в джаве, чтобы памяти заняли много, когда нужно, потом освободили ссылки, и память тоже освободилась?

Comment: Никак, в ручную нельзя этого сделать, сборщик мусора не управляем, он работает сам по себе. Вызов `System.gc()` не всегда дает нужный результат. Возможно это могло бы помочь - если бы вы, использовали ссылки на объект. Но `int` не является ссылкой на объект, а лишь содержит значение из стека. Вот если бы вы, использовали бы `Integer` то да, возможно бы он и скушал, но присваивая `null`, вы и так уже сказали бы `gc`, что нужно убрать этот объект, и вызывать в ручную не придется. А вообще со временем `gc` сам все уберет, по этому наберитесь терпения.

Comment: @And и все же тут массив...

Comment: Конечно же, имелось в виду System.gc(), а не gs(), это опечатка.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное все же System.GC (Garbage Collector)

Спецификация языка Java не гарантирует вызов сборщика мусора при вызове System.gc 
Это всего лишь предложение JVM запустить "сборщик мусора".